# ActivityClientRecord NullPointerException only on android5.0

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a crash that only happen on android 5.0 and 5.0.2, but according to the stack I can not find any of my code, and any evidence, what's more, I still can't reproduce this crash in my android5.0 device. While from the crash report it happened many times, it is the top 1 crash of my app, can anybody help on this?

LocalizedMessage: Attempt to read from field 'android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.activity' on a null object reference
Message: Attempt to read from field 'android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.activity' on a null object reference
Type: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.activity' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.activity' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1456)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
Back traces ends.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I don't know which code cause this crash, so I can't post code

Comment: follow your activity, which one you open and post the code where its carsh